# Verified account like twitter

Tags: mysql, account

I would like to install on my website a «verefied account» feature. But I wondered what was the best way to get there, with MySQL and PHP?

I tried to put a column «verified», in witch I post the badge picture name (verified.png), but by doing it this way, users with no verified account saw the space occupied by the badge, with empty space with an X in the upper left corner.

So, any idea on the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go deeper. You are missing huge part of web design and PHP.

**What's the correct way too implement this?**

1- Add a Boolean/Bit "Verified" Column 0/1

2- In your PHP page, you need a simple condition:

```
If(Column("Verified") == True) {
 echo '<img src=\"verified.png\" />'
} else { 
   //Nothing! 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a column `verified_account` in your `users` table. When you want to validate an account, you should add something like `YES` or `NO` to the proper user. Then, on your page, you only have to call something like:

```
SELECT verified_account FROM users WHERE ID = $session_id
IF verified_account = YES
echo = YOUR_IMAGE_HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add a row to your mysql database that is of type ENUM, and set it value to 0 if not verified, and 1 if verified. Then check the value of the ENUM for that particular user and if it is one, display the image.